# How to use face authentication using Biometric api

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I used fingerprint authentication using Biometric api and its working.I need to do the same for face recognition ,like for a login button click instead of password i'll be using face authentication .

So is it possible with Biometric api or I have to use Open cv?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can authenticate all form factors (i.e. face, iris, fingerprint, etc.) using the AndroidX Biometric library as explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) and [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html). Essentially, your app is not responsible for targeting specific form-factors. The library does the work for you. If a device supports facial biometrics, then your user will see a prompt for facial authentication; if your device supports fingerprint biometrics, then your user will see a prompt for fingerprint authentication; and so on.

Comment: Your blog was way more helpful.

Comment: and what is the case when device support both fingerprint and face unlock?    In my device fingerprint and face unlock both available but everytime it opens fingerprint popup and when I delete all the fingerprint it show not fingerprint enrolled error.  Can you help??

Comment: @AlokSingh As far as I know: Biometric auth can be 'weak' or 'strong'. Only strong will be used. The App can not change this. So when Finger is strong and Face is weak only Finger is available. It seems that this will be changed in Android 11 (https://www.biometricupdate.com/202003/biometric-features-in-android-11-give-developers-more-authentication-security-options). Maybe two more links to this topis: https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_3_10_biometric_sensors and https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd

Comment: Am I right that face unlock available only for devices with special hardware camera, like Pixel4?

Comment: Also, what is your suggestion about fingerprint login to an app for multiple users? Is it possible, or user must be logged in to the OS first?

Comment: If both(like finger print and face)will support on the device then how to opt for one of those., am always getting fingerprint not face ., if i remove fingerprint on the device then only it is asking for Face recognition.

Answer (score -1):

BOTH BIOMETRIC SAFE PARAMETERS ARE:

1. FACE
2. FINGERPRINT
3. FINGERPRINT READER FOR LIFE SIGN DIRECTLY IN SYNCH WITH ALL PARAMETERS.
4. FAIL PROOF:ADDED VERBAL COMM. TO AUTHORIZE THE AUTHENTICATION